# Spatial Point Pattern Analysis Python

Tags: pyspark, geolocation, location, geospatial, anomaly-detection

I am observing grid patterns in my raw location data and am trying to clean such locations without getting rid of a lot of valid locations or any other pattern that is common which I can filter out.

As I am new to location data, I am not sure what are the methods I could explore to get rid of these data points. I will first try to look into DBSCAN, but am hoping to seek more advice on what other methods I can explore. The dataset is quite large (petabytes) so I have to keep in mind the scalability issue. I tried searching up on spatial point analysis patterns but I am not able to find anything that might help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you define "valid" versus invalid locations?

Comment: @JonNordby when plotting, the points should not form horizontal/vertical lines, i just need to make the grids less obvious. Also, I used rdd.flatmap then collect() to plot this graph using matplotlib but when i converted the pyspark df to pandas df and use matplotlib, the plot was perfect. Meaning that those points that form the grids actually do not exist but is plotted when i use .collect()

Comment: If one method of plotting gives the right plot and another does not, that sounds like you have a plotting problem, not a data problem?

Comment: @JonNordby yes, i am now speculating it is the plotting problem. But i can't seem to find anyone that is facing my issue. I am not sure why matplotlib plots non-existent additional spatial points that do not exist in the dataset (hence forming the grids) when using .rdd.flatmap() and collect() to convert the col to list to feed them in as arguments to plt.scatter(). But when i convert to pandas df, matplotlib gives perfect plot.

Comment: You need to provide an MRE for anyone to be able to help with that, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JonNordby sorry, it is not the plotting problem. when zooming in, the grid like patterns exist, could you advice reasons for this and methods to clean this?